# Apache RewriteRule for missing folders and files using httpd.conf NOT .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I've got this in a few sites, stuck in a `.htaccess` file at the site root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /rewrite.cfm?rewrite_path=$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Can I do this in a `httpd.conf` file? I'd rather avoid `.htaccess` if possible.

Open to other suggestions as well. Using Apache 2.4 on Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

You may use this modified rule in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /rewrite.cfm?rewrite_path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Starting `/` is optional so that rule would work in both cases and you must remove `R` (redirect) flag as intent is to do an internal rewrite instead of a redirect that exposes your internal URL in browser.